# How can I extend my stay in America for 6 more days?

Tags: usa, visa-extensions, texas

I was wondering, if I wanted to extend my stay for an extra 6 days, how would this happen? Some info, I'm a British citizen traveling to America with an ESTA, I'm in the state of Texas, and I've stayed currently for 25 days, I was wanting to stay for 37 now.

Comment: Normally, you can stay for 3 months with an ESTA/VWP. Why do you think something needs to be extended? What does the stamp in your passport say regarding how long you can stay?

Comment: My passport stamp doesn't say anything about going back, just that I was accepted on the 4th, and for the extension, it was because my girlfriend is going to be giving a speach and I wanted to be there for it

Comment: @Cam if the immigration officer did not write a date in your passport, you can look up your "admit until" date at the link in my answer.  Did the officer not write "WT" on the stamp?

Comment: @cam, you almost certainly have 90 days.  If I was you I would phone the relevant authority and check that.

Comment: Consider just getting married while you're there.  Your gf can get an actual (  ;)  ) passport, a UK one (for now a European one, a staggering advantage).  For yourself if you ever want to work in the US it will be a little easier.

Comment: @Fattie marrying a UK citizen does not by itself make someone eligible for a UK passport.  To get that, one has to naturalize in the UK, a prerequisite for which is living in the UK for a number of years.  Getting married could make immigrating to the UK somewhat easier, but it's also possible for unmarried partners to immigrate to the UK.

Comment: Extension...to what?  Did you ever tell any authorities you were going to be staying exactly 25 days?

Comment: "marrying a UK citizen does not by itself make someone eligible for a UK passport."  correct, but it's *reasonably* easy.  (more of a formality.  whereas in the US it's a huge PITA)

Comment: ("Getting married could make immigrating to the UK somewhat easier" it's much much easier if you are married, and tremendously easier again if you have children.)  For anyone who's trying to be "international" or thinks they can be a "PT", it's always best to just go ahead and get married and have children, and not waste time.

Answer (score 28):

If you traveled with ESTA then you've been admitted under the visa waiver program (VWP).  One condition of the VWP is that you cannot extend your stay or change your status.  The literal answer to your question, therefore, is "no, you cannot."

You must therefore leave by the date in your I-94 record, which you can look up at https://i94.cbp.dhs.gov.  That date should also be written on your admission stamp, in your passport.

VWP visitors are normally admitted for 90 days.  Since you're planning to spend a little more than a month in the US, it is unclear why you think this would require extending your stay.  If you indicated a shorter stay when you arrived, there's no need to notify the US government of your change in plans.  If your period of admission was curtailed for some reason, then you cannot change it.

Comment: No, I'm not staying for another 37, I'm staying for a total of 37

Comment: @Cam I just noticed that.

Comment: Also, how would I go about moving my flight back? Or would I need to get in contact with the company I booked my tickets through?

Comment: @Cam either the company that booked your tickets or directly with the airline.  You can ask a separate question about that if there isn't one already.

Comment: Be prepared that moving a flight might cost you an arm and a leg. Because they _can_.

Comment: Partly: when you booked initially months ahead, you were booking into deeply discounted seats (technically price buckets). But when you *change late in the game* those discounted seats/buckets on your new flight have already been sold or withdrawn, most seats have been sold, and you are stuck with leftovers at the highest price tier.

Comment: @Cam The last time I found myself in a position of changing a return date we simply threw away the tickets and bought new ones.  That's the sort of cost you're likely looking at.

Comment: @Harper Additionally, unless you initially booked a fully-refundable fare class (which is unlikely,) most airlines will also charge a quite significant change fee on top of the applicable fare difference.